# Declaring anonymous struct in for loop, clang fails to compile

Tags: c, c99

Code declaring anonymous structs in a for loop worked fine in gcc with -std=c99/gnu99

```
for (struct {int foo; int bar;} i = {0}; i.foo < 10; i.foo++);
```

However when I switch to clang instead I got the error:

```
error: declaration of non-local variable in 'for' loop
```

Why is this an error? Why would it allow some types (e.g. "int") but not others (e.g. struct {int foo;}) ? This seems inconsistent. Does clang fail to implement c99 correctly or is that code invalid c99 and gcc just happens to support it?

Does anyone know of a way to declare more than one type of variable in a for loop that is supported by clang? (This is useful for macros.)

EDIT:

Since people asked why this is useful I will paste some example code:

```
#define TREE_EACH(head, node, field, iterator) for ( \
    /* initialize */ \
    struct { \
        node* cur; \
        node* stack[((head)->th_root == 0? 0: (head)->th_root->field.avl_height) + 1]; \
        uint32_t stack_size; \
    } iterator = {.cur = (head)->th_root, .stack_size = 0}; \
    /* while */ \
    iterator.cur != 0; \
    /* iterate */ \
    (iterator.stack_size += (iterator.cur->field.avl_right != 0) \
        ? (iterator.stack[iterator.stack_size] = avl_right, 1) \
        : 0), \
    (iterator.cur = (iterator.cur->field.avl_left == 0) \
        ? iterator.cur->field.avl_left \
        : (iterator.stack_size > 0? (iterator.stack_size--, iterator.stack[iterator.stack_size]): 0)) \
)
```

This is a really convenient macro that I wrote which iterates over an AVL tree in depth-first order on the stack. Since declaring anonymous structs in the for loop is not allowed though I have to make the macro less intuitive to use. I could not possible out-source the declaration to the rest of the tree since it uses a variable length array.

Comment: Why do you need a struct as a local variable in a for loop? What purpose does it achieve?

Comment: For the record VS 2008 also cannot compile that.

Comment: Jay: It is useful in "foreach" style macro where the iterator is complex (requiring many different types) and anonymous as to not pollute the namespace. Declaring them above the for would essentially make declarations/identifiers leek out into the scope where the macro is used unless two blocks/end braces is used which is unintuitive.

Comment: Is someone able to answer why it reportedly compiles with gcc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm respectfully unconvinced by the previous answers. It builds successfully with gcc (with `-Wall -pedantic`), only not with clang nor Visual Studio.

Microsoft have acknowledged as a bug an extremely similar issue with Visual Studio at this [Microsoft Connect bug item](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/624410/visual-c-compiler-fails-to-parse-a-for-init-statement-that-starts-with-a-class-specifier).

6.8.5 is saying that declarations of identifiers inside the *for-init-expression* cannot be `typedef`, `extern` or `static` (the only storage class specifiers other than `auto` and `register`).

The storage class specifier `auto` in C99 is default and is implicit. The struct type and identifier `i` are then auto (have scope within that code block). Surely the code is then valid? I don't see how 6.8.5 is forbidding the declaration of a type.

I suggest that gcc is correct, and it's a bug with the implementation by clang and Visual Studio.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio is primarily a C++ compiler; in C mode, it doesn't support C99. I'm not sure whether the C99 and C++ rules are identical.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for now and I'm eagerly expecting a reply from they guys that think that this isn't valid C99.

Comment: C 1999 6.7.2.1 7: “The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit.” Therefore, `struct {int foo; int bar;} i` declares a type. This violates 6.8.5 3, which requires that the declaration in a `for` declare **only** identifiers for objects having storage class auto or register. It is quite simple: The `for` may only declare identifiers, but this one declares a type. It therefore violates the standard.

Comment: @HannesLandeholm: We can prove the definition of the type is the reason clang produces this error: When you declare the type in advance, with a typedef or struct tag, and change the declaration in the `for` to use the name or tag, then clang accepts the source text **even though it still declares the same object**. This proves it is not declaring the **object** that clang objects to but is the **type**.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm still not convinced that acraig5075 is wrong. The official document does not put emphasis on "only" as in "only identifiers". That emphasis was added by you when you quote it. The way I interpret that sentence (as it continues after that) is that it simply addresses that identifiers declared by it can only have the storage class "auto" or "register". It does not explicitly say that type declaration should not be allowed. Also even calling it a "type declaration" is dubious as an anonymous struct declaration is essentially not a type declaration. It's just a bare type.

Comment: @HannesLandeholm: 6.7.2.1 7 **explicitly** says it is a type declaration. I did not alter the emphasis in any quoted text. clang in fact accepts the object declaration when the type declaration is omitted. You ignore all these facts, which point to clang interpreting the standard as I have described, and instead conclude it is a bug in both clang and Visual Studio. What is the chance that compilers written by two different teams would have the same esoteric bug that coincides precisely with an interpretation of the C standard?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you link the source that puts "only" in bold, because my document did not. Also how clang is implemented is not really relevant to whether something is legit C99 or not. Especially when other compilers disagree. Shouldn't the default interpretation when in doubt to go with the simpler one (Occam's razor if you will) and the simplest interpretation is the one that distinguishes the least between identifier declarations in a for statement and between other identifier declarations in a function body?

Comment: There is room for interpretation, though! 'shall only declare identifiers for [...]' Variant 1: 'only' refers to everything that could be declared, types, variables, ... Variant 2: 'only' refers only to the identifiers. In second variant, as there is no identifier declared for the unnamed type, only for the instance of, we'd be absolutely fine... Apparently, GCC and MSVC chose second variant in contrast to clang...

Comment: @HannesLandeholm: Re “Can you link the source that puts "only" in bold”: No. Once again, I did not quote any part of the C standard as having “only” in bold. I used bold only in my own words, as a tool for expressing my meaning. My comments do not rely on any part of the C standard having text in bold.

Comment: Re “The struct type and identifier `i` are then auto”: Neither types nor identifiers can be “auto.” `auto` is a storage class specifier and affects the storage duration of objects. Types and identifiers do not have storage duration. The object named by `i` will have automatic storage duration.

Comment: Re “I don't see how 6.8.5 is forbidding the declaration of a type”: C 2018 6.8.5 3 says the declaration of a `for` loop  “shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.” By declaring a type, the declaration does not declare only identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`. It declares an identifier and declares a type.

Answer (score 6):

## Summary

The potential violation of the C standard lies with this sentence in C 2018 6.8.5 3:

> The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

Since `struct { int i; float f; }` declares both a type and an identifier, there is some question about how to interpret 6.8.5 3. It appears to me that:

- It is likely the committee intended to prohibit declaring anything but
  identifiers for `auto` or `register` objects.
- This use case where a type is incidentally declared may not have been considered.
- Allowing this incidental declaration would be harmless and not considerably out of line with the intent.

(I would invite anybody more familiar with C committee records to bring to our attention anything pertaining to this.)

(I give references to the 2018 C standard in this answer, but the language
is old and exists in previous versions, perhaps with some different numbering
of clauses or paragraphs.)

## Both a Type and an Identifier Are Declared

The declaration in the following `for` statement declares both an identifier `s` and an unnamed type:

```
for (struct { int i; float f; } s = { 0, 0 }; s.i < 25; ++s.i, s.f = s.i/10.f)
    …
```

We know it declares a type because C 2018 6.7.2.1 8 says:

> The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit.

Per 6.7.2.1 1, `struct { int i; float f; }` is a struct-or-union-specifier, and, within it, `int i; float f;` is a struct-declaration list. So this source code matches the description of 6.7.2.1 8, so it declares a type.

## The Language of the C Standard is Ambiguous

C 2018 6.8.5 3 says:

> The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

As a matter of English grammar and use, several meanings are possible for this sentence, including:

1. The only things the declaration shall declare are identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.
2. The only identifiers the declaration shall declare are identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.
3. The only identifiers for objects the declaration shall declare are identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

Primarily, the problem is the “only” is not adjacent to the thing it is modifying. The “only” could be modifying “identifiers” or “objects” or “storage class.” One might prefer the modifier to modify the candidate nearest it, but the authors of sentences do not always construct them thusly. (Grammatically, it could also modify “having,” thus qualifying the objects as having only storage class `auto` or `register` and not having anything else, such as not having size or other properties. We easily rule out this meaning on semantic rather than grammatical grounds.)

These samples illustrate differences between the meanings:

```
static int s                 // Prohibited by 1, 2, and 3.
extern int s(int)            // Prohibited by 1 and 2, permitted by 3.
struct { int i; float f; } s // Prohibited by 1, permitted by 2 and 3.
int s                        // Permitted by 1, 2, and 3.
```

## Effects May Illuminate Intent

It does not appear there is a reason for preferring any of these meanings based on difficulties of implementing C. To see this, consider that a C implementation may easily rewrite:

```
for (declaration; …; …) …
```

to the equivalent code:

```
{ declaration; for (; …; …) … }
```

Thus, if a C implementation can support declarations and `for` statements in general, it can support general declarations in a `for` statement without significant additional effort.

What then is the purpose of 6.8.5 3?

The declaration in a `for` statement provides convenience. It provides a nice way of declaring some iterator or other object used to control the loop, while limiting the scope to the `for` statement (which is a benefit for avoiding bugs). It does not provide any new function. Given this, I expect 6.8.5 3 was written with the intent of enabling the declaration to serve this purpose without opening it up to other purposes. It would be odd, although not impossible, to use either of the first two sample declarations above in a `for` statement.

If so, I suspect the surface intent of the committee was meaning 1 but that they did not consider the situation where an unnamed type is incidentally declared. When we reflect on the third sample, using a structure, we see that it is unusual but is not too out of line with the customary use of a `for` statement:

- It arises naturally as a solution to the problem that only one declaration may be present in the declaration part of a `for` statement, yet sometimes it is useful to manage the loop with multiple objects of different types.
- It is still an object with automatic storage generation, as intended for `for` loops.
- The type that is technically declared is not needed outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @Aconcagua: C11 [§6.8.5 Iteration statements ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5p3): _The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`._  That is not in the section on `for` only, but in the generic 'iteration statements' section.

Comment: As I see, in C2x (N3047) the 6.8.5p3 is not changed. Do you know whether WG14 considered the ambiguity of the 6.8.5p3? Is there a corresponding DR perhaps?

Comment: Off-topic: In C11 I cannot find an explicit semantics of `auto` storage class. Searching for `auto` (case sensitive, whole words only) gives 11 results. None of these 11 results answers the question "what is the explicit semantics of `auto` storage class?"

Comment: @pmor: The behavior of the `auto` storage class is defined by text that specifies the storage durations of objects that do not have `static` or `_Thread_local`. C 2018 6.2.4 3 says an object whose identifier is declared without `_Thread_local` and either with external linkage or with internal linkage or with `static` has static storage duration. 6.2.4 4 says an object whose identifier is declared with `_Thread_local` has thread storage duration. 6.2.4 5 says an object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without `static` has automatic storage duration. So 6.2.4 5 covers `auto`.

Comment: As I understand, there is no explicit association of `auto` storage class specifier with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 3):

It's not allowed in C99.  §6.8.5 says:

> 3 The declaration part of a for statement shall only declare
>   identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

The declaration you've shown declares a type in addition to the object `i`, and a type is not an identifier for an object.

Comment: @Aconcagua: It is in C 2011 draft N1570: “The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.” And it is in the official version of C 2018.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could add outer for-loop for each struct member that loops exactly once. It is ugly but at least from use perspective it will be the same

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for a small piece of code (https://github.com/kutoga/CArr) and there is a simple solution for your problem / code:

```
for (__auto_type i = ({
      struct {int foo; int bar;} _i = {0};
      _i;
    }); i.foo < 10; i.foo++)
```

The solution is to put the anonymous type in `({...})` and assign it to an `__auto_type`. That works fine with gcc and clang.