# Declare structure within for?

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, clang, language-lawyer

Apple LLVM 9.1.0 with clang-902.0.39.2, using `-std=c11`, accepts:

```
typedef struct { int i; float f; } S;
for (S s = { 0, 0 }; s.i < 25; ++s.i, s.f = i/10.f)
    …
```

but rejects:

```
for (struct { int i; float f; } s = { 0, 0 }; s.i < 25; ++s.i, s.f = s.i/10.f)
    …
```

with the message:

> error: declaration of non-local variable in 'for' loop

Is Clang correct to reject this, because it violates some constraint in the C standard? Which clause and paragraph? Or is it a Clang bug?

Comment: I reopened this because I drafted a new answer exploring the situation with more analysis and because I think the accepted answer in [the previous original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903232/declaring-anonymous-struct-in-for-loop-clang-fails-to-compile) is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summary

The potential violation of the C standard lies with this sentence in C 2018 6.8.5 3:

> The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

Since `struct { int i; float f; }` declares both a type and an identifier, there is some question about how to interpret 6.8.5 3. It appears to me that:

- It is likely the committee intended to prohibit declaring anything but
  identifiers for `auto` or `register` objects.
- This use case where a type is incidentally declared may not have been considered.
- Allowing this incidental declaration would be harmless and not considerably out of line with the intent.

(I would invite anybody more familiar with C committee records to bring to our attention anything pertaining to this.)

(I give references to the 2018 C standard in this answer, but the language
is old and exists in previous versions, perhaps with some different numbering
of clauses or paragraphs.)

## The Declaration Declares a Type, Structure Member Identifiers, and an Object Identifier

Consider the declaration in this `for` statement:

```
for (struct { int i; float f; } s = { 0, 0 }; s.i < 25; ++s.i, s.f = s.i/10.f)
    …
```

It declares:

- A type, the untagged structure.
- Identifiers `i` and `f` for the members of the structure.
- The object `s`.

## The Language of the C Standard is Ambiguous

C 2018 6.8.5 3 says:

> The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

As a matter of English grammar and use, several meanings are possible for this sentence, including:

1. The only things the declaration shall declare are identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.
2. The only identifiers the declaration shall declare are identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.
3. The only identifiers for objects the declaration shall declare are identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`.

Primarily, the problem is the “only” is not adjacent to the thing it is modifying. The “only” could be modifying “identifiers” or “objects” or “storage class.” One might prefer the modifier to modify the candidate nearest it, but the authors of sentences do not always construct them thusly. (Grammatically, it could also modify “having,” thus qualifying the objects as having only storage class `auto` or `register` and not having anything else, such as not having size or other properties. We easily rule out this meaning on semantic rather than grammatical grounds.)

These samples illustrate differences between the meanings:

```
static int s                 // Prohibited by 1, 2, and 3.
extern int s(int)            // Prohibited by 1 and 2, permitted by 3.
struct { int i; float f; } s // Prohibited by 1 and 2, permitted by 3.
int s                        // Permitted by 1, 2, and 3.
```

## Effects May Illuminate Intent

It does not appear there is a reason for preferring any of these meanings based on difficulties of implementing C. To see this, consider that a C implementation may easily rewrite:

```
for (declaration; …; …) …
```

to the equivalent code:

```
{ declaration; for (; …; …) … }
```

Thus, if a C implementation can support declarations and `for` statements in general, it can support general declarations in a `for` statement without significant additional effort.

What then is the purpose of 6.8.5 3?

The declaration in a `for` statement provides convenience. It provides a nice way of declaring some iterator or other object used to control the loop, while limiting the scope to the `for` statement (which is a benefit for avoiding bugs). It does not provide any new function. Given this, I expect 6.8.5 3 was written with the intent of enabling the declaration to serve this purpose without opening it up to other purposes. It would be odd, although not impossible, to use either of the first two sample declarations above in a `for` statement.

If so, I suspect the surface intent of the committee was meaning 1 but that they did not consider the situation where a structure type is incidentally declared. When we reflect on the third sample, using a structure, we see that it is unusual but is not too out of line with the customary use of a `for` statement:

- It arises naturally as a solution to the problem that only one declaration may be present in the declaration part of a `for` statement, yet sometimes it is useful to manage the loop with multiple objects of different types.
- It is still an object with automatic storage generation, as intended for `for` loops.
- The type that is technically declared is not needed outside the `for` loop, nor are the names of its members.

Answer (score 3):

C11:

> 6.8.5.3 The for statement
>
> 1 The statement
>
> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression expression-3 is
>   evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a
>   declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.158)

Left out [2], just speaking of handling ommited clauses/expressions...

> 158) Thus, clause-1 specifies initialization for the loop, possibly declaring one or more variables for use in the loop; the controlling expression, expression-2, specifies an evaluation made before each iteration, such that execution of the loop continues until the expression compares equal to 0; and expression-3 specifies an operation (such as incrementing) that is performed after each iteration.

Nothing mentioned about any restrictions. So as second example is a valid declaration – and I assume clang does not complain about the following either:

```
void f(void)
{
    struct { int x, y; } point;
    // use point...
}
```

– then the second example should be valid C code, so as far as I see, clang is wrong in rejecting.

Comment: There may be a restriction somewhere else in the standard, and I suspect there is. Consider `for (static int i = 0;…)`. We know that is not what the declaration inside a `for` is for, so it would make sense that somewhere else in the C standard there is a restriction that things declared inside a `for` must have an automatic storage duration, for example. If we find that, we might see whether its phrasing also excludes declaring new structure types inside a `for` (Clang is right) or not (Clang is wrong—developer misinterpreted the restriction?).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point. But I looked over the subsequent chapters of the standard as well, although admittted, not too thoroughly, as they address totally different topics. Annex A.2.3.6.8.5 comes back to, but no further information either (it is informative only anyway). The index only references the already stated section.

Comment: It almost looks as if static variables in for loop initializers actually were legal. Interesting: C++17 has similar wording, but a bit more extent. GCC rejects static initializer for C, but not for C++! Not sure which of both is correct according to the (respective?) standard...

Comment: C11 [§6.8.5 Iteration statements ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5p3): _The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`._  That is not in the section on `for` only, but in the generic 'iteration statements' section.

Comment: I'm not sure whether declaring the identifiers for the members of a `struct` is meant to be included in 'only declare identifiers for objects'.  Since the structure is tagless when declared in the loop, it is only the members that might run foul of that 'only' restriction, but it isn't 100% clear to me that a structure type is an object.  A tagged structure might run foul of it — and distinguishing between tagged and tagless structures would probably not be intentional.  A tagged structure type would only be visible within the loop (§6.8.5 ¶5). It feels to me like an ambiguity in the standard.

Comment: _"It isn't 100% clear to me that a structure type is an object"_ — I'm clear that the structure `s` is an object, but it has storage class `auto` so it is OK.  I'm not clear that the type used to define `s` is "an object"; it is a type, not an object, at least in general.

Comment: Uh, missed that phrase, will I have to append it to the answer? There is room for interpretation, though! *'shall only declare identifiers for [...]'* Variant 1: *'only'* refers to everything that could be declared, types, variables, ... Variant 2: *'only'* refers only to the identifiers. In second variant, as there is no identifier declared for the unnamed type, only for the instance of, we'd be absolutely fine... Apparently, GCC and MSVC chose second variant in contrast to clang...